# I am trying to make a video chat-app using imagezmq and opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, zeromq

Here is the code:

Server:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imagezmq

image_hub = imagezmq.ImageHub()

while True:  # show streamed images until Ctrl-C
  win_name = "Feed"
  image = image_hub.recv_image()
  img = cv2.imdecode(image, 1)
  cv2.imshow(win_name, img) 

  cv2.waitKey(1)

  image_hub.send_reply(b'OK')
```

Client:

```
import socket
import time
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import imagezmq
import cv2
import numpy as np
sender = imagezmq.ImageSender(connect_to='tcp://192.168.0.12:5555')
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
time.sleep(2.0) 

while True:  # send images as stream until Ctrl-C
  frame = vs.read()
  img_arr = np.array(bytearray(frame))
  sender.send_image("Img",img_arr)
```

And i get the error:

```
      img = cv2.imdecode(image, 1)
      TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'buf'
```

on the server
I have checked online but could not find a suitable answer
Note: i am not that experienced in this.

Answer (score 1):

according to imagezmq's [documentation](https://github.com/jeffbass/imagezmq), one does not use any imdecode, and one does not use any `bytearray()` calls.

you just send numpy arrays back and forth.

further, I would advise against using `imutils`, in particular the `VideoStream` wrapper. use OpenCV's `VideoCapture`. check for `isOpened()` before trying to read. when reading with `ok, frame = cap.read()`, check if the read frame is `ok`, otherwise break the reading loop and discard the value in `frame`.